# Merge the JSON data with same value in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON Data that I am getting from URL. I want to merge the data which has **same Value** Below is the sample data. I have searched through the Internet,but i didn't got the solution. All i found is for **same Keys**.

```
  [ {
    "banana": [
      {
        "color": yellow,
        "size": "small"
      },
      {
        "size": "medium"
      },
      {
        "size": "large"
      }
    ],
    "process_name": "fruits"},{
    "carnivores": [
      {
        "name": "lion"
      },
      {
        "name": "tiger"
      },
      {
        "name": "chetah"
      },
      {
        "name": "dianosaur"
      }
    ],
    "process_name": "animal"}, {
    "apple": [
      {
        "color": red,
        "size": "large"
      }
    ],
    "process_name": "fruits"}]
```

And I want to merge the data of `"process_name" :"fruits"`  into one array as below and the result should be

```
[{
"banana": [
  {
    "color": yellow,
    "size": "small"
  },
  {
    "size": "medium"
  },
  {
    "size": "large"
  }
],
"apple": [
  {
    "color": red,
    "size": "large"
  }
],
"process_name": "fruits"  }, {
"carnivores": [
  {
    "name": "lion"
  },
  {
    "name": "tiger"
  },
  {
    "name": "chetah"
  },
  {
    "name": "dianosaur"
  }
],
"process_name": "animal"}]
```

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some snippet to start:

```js
// data definition
const json_before = [ {
  "banana": [
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "size": "small"
    },
    {
      "size": "medium"
    },
    {
      "size": "large"
    }
  ],
  "process_name": "fruits"},
{
  "carnivores": [
    {
      "name": "lion"
    },
    {
      "name": "tiger"
    },
    {
      "name": "chetah"
    },
    {
      "name": "dianosaur"
    }
  ],
  "process_name": "animal"},
{
  "apple": [
    {
      "color": "red",
      "size": "large"
    }
  ],
  "process_name": "fruits"
}];

// processing
const json_after = json_before.reduce((arr, next) => {
  const exist = arr.find(el => el.process_name === next.process_name);
  if (exist) Object.assign(exist, next);
  else arr.push(next);
  return arr;
}, []);

// check
console.log(json_after);
```

The main idea is to use `reduce` for array traversing. To shorten the processing code, I've used `Object.assign` to modify previuosly added element, although in real code it's better to use `Object.keys` and manually check whether the properties of the previous object aren't overwritten.

Note that this is mutating the source data (check by adding `console.log(json_before)`). Again, if you don't want this, you should clone each element yourself, without direct object assignment.